# How action mapping is done with struts with the help of struts-config.xml?

Tags: struts2, struts, struts-1

I would like to know how the action mapping is done by struts reading `struts-config.xml` file.

Will this differ between Struts1 and Struts2 - the way in which the action mapping is done?

Help me know about it.

Answer (score 1):

In Struts1 action mapping is defined by the `struts-config.xml` action tag.

In Struts2 action mapping is defined by the `struts.xml` action tag.

**Note, that action mapping implementation in Struts2 vary on which plugin provides it. The plugins also provide their own action configs.**